# difflib get_close_matches error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, difflib

So, I tried the program below to run eveything was working except for the get_close_matches() part

Code:

```
from difflib import get_close_matches

class Library:

    def __init__(self,books):
        self.books=books
        
    def display_books(self):
        print("-----Available Books-----")
        for book in self.books:
            print(book)
    def borrow_books(self,borrow_book):
        if borrow_book in self.books:
            print("Get your book")
            self.books.remove(borrow_book)

        else:
            print("Book not available")
    def return_books(self,return_book):
        print("You have returned the book")
        self.books.append(return_book)
    
books=['C','C++','Java','Python']
o = Library(books)
msg="""
    Select the choices below
        1.Display Book
        2.Borrow Book
        3.Recieve Book
    """
while True:
    print(msg)
    ch=int(input("Enter your Choice : "))
    if ch == 1:
        o.display_books()
    elif ch == 2:
        book = input("Enter the book name to borrow : ")
        if book in books:
            o.borrow_books(book)
        elif get_close_matches(book, books):
            chooice=input("Did you mean %s"%get_close_matches(book,books)[0] ,"Enter Y for yes N for no")
            if chooice == "Y" or "y":
                print( books[get_close_matches(book,books)[0]])
            elif chooice == "N" or "n":
                print( "Entered book is not available")
        
    elif ch == 3:
        book = input("Enter the book name to return : ")
        o.return_books(book)
    else:
        print("Tq")
        quit()
```

this was the code nd
the output is :

```
Select the choices below
    1.Display Book
    2.Borrow Book
    3.Recieve Book
```

Enter your Choice : 2
Enter the book name to borrow : pyton
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "library_management.py", line 45, in 
chooice=input("Did you mean %s"%get_close_matches(book,books)[0] ,"Enter Y for yes N for no")
TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 2

i dunno why i got this error did i mess up somewhere or did i miss out any variable
plzz helo i'm just a beginner so Plz help me on this

Comment: Hint: `input('a', 'b')` would give the same error. It's not `get_close_matches()` that's complaining, it's `input()` that accepts at most one argument. In fact, the error message says "input expected ...".

Comment: Thnx sir,i got a good understanding now ,program works fine now